# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get' Django beginner

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a very simple code in Django and I've this error which comes everytime.

The content of the form is well saved in the model but this error shows up when I want to use reverse: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

There is my code:

views.py:

```
class PastaView(View):

    template_name = 'pasta.html'
    form_class = PastaForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item = get_object_or_404(Pasta, url=kwargs['hash'])
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'pasta': item, 'form': self.form_class})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        item = get_object_or_404(Pasta, url=kwargs['hash'])
        if form.is_valid():
            item.text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            item.save()
        return reverse('detail_pasta', kwargs={'hash': item.url})
```

forms.py:

```
class PastaForm(Form):

    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

models.py:

```
class Pasta(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text', blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(verbose_name='url', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.text

    def save(self):
        super(Pasta, self).save()

        if not self.url:
            self.url = baseconvert(str(self).id, BASE10, BASE62)
            self.save()
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/pastabin/B/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pastabin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/snaaail/.virtualenvs/copy_pasta/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/snaaail/.virtualenvs/copy_pasta/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /pastabin/B/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `post` method is returning the result of `reverse`, which is a string, ie the URL. You actually need to return a redirect response.

The `redirect` shortcut can do this for you directly:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return redirect('detail_pasta', hash=item.url)
```

Comment: Thanks you, I didn't know about the difference.